# Symmetric triangle inTikZ-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

I would like to draw a commutative triangle with tikzcd where the entries have different sizes.

```
 \[
  \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=15pt]
  \mathcal{C} \ar{rr}  \ar{dr} & & S(\tau) \ar{dl} \\
   & \mathsf{Set} &
  \end{tikzcd}
 \]
```

This produces a slight asymmetry (the arrow on the right is more slanted, and the middle entry is not in the middle):

[image]

One solution is to use the following tikzcd-option:

```
 cells={nodes={align=center,text width=\widthof{$S(\tau)$}}}
```

The output looks as follows:

[image]

But now the arrow doesn't start at the left entry. How to make this happen?

Comment: Off topic: in `xy` it is `@!` or `@!0`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update

This feature is mentioned in the Ti*k*Z manual, namely III.20.3.2.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={1cm,between origins}]
    \mathcal{C}\ar{rr}\ar{dr} && S(\tau,..............)\ar{dl} \\
    & \mathsf{Set}
\end{tikzcd}
```

### Old Answer

The column-separating symbol `&` accepts an optional argument. Just like `\\[6pt]` does, `&[6]` adds the *current* `col sep` by `6`...`pt` by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=15pt]
        \mathcal{C}\ar{rr}\ar{dr} &[6]& S(\tau)\ar{dl} \\
        & \mathsf{Set}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I don't understand why. Could you explain what you mean by "adds the current col sep by default" and why it gives the desired result?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Symbol 1 just changed the separation in between the columns for the two left columns. 6pt instead of the 15pt which are your default. The wider triangle looks more symmetric, but it isn't.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I thought it is **6+15pt** just like `\\[6pt]` add additional spaces. Any way, @Martin Brandenburg you can check out the `matrix` library of Ti*k*Z, on which `tikz-cd` bases.

Comment: @Symbol1 You are right. It does. Btw.: Thanks for that cool feature. I have seen a lot of posts here, where the answer was "change globally or use many many &&& in order to get different column seps in your graph". Is that feature new? First time I am seeing it.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Not sure. Maybe I saw this feature from something about `pgfplotstable`.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `[start anchor={[xshift=-5pt]}]` to shift the starting point of your arrow.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
 \[
  \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=15pt,cells={nodes={align=center,text width=\widthof{$S(\tau)$}}}]
  \mathcal{C} \ar[start anchor={[xshift=-5pt]}]{rr}  \ar{dr} & & S(\tau) \ar{dl} \\
   & \mathsf{Set} &
  \end{tikzcd}
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added that possibility here, too...

Answer (score 2):

For a real symmetry speaking of the arrows, you will have to increase the width and the hight of the upper left node.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=15pt]
      \phantom{S(\tau)}\mathllap{\mathcal{C}}\ar{rr}\ar{dr} & & S(\tau)\ar{dl} \\
    & \textsf{Set}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the diagonal arrows are starting and ending in the very same place (but mirrored).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution with the `psmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.25, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=2pt, rowsep=0.9cm, colsep=0.7cm}
\begin{psmatrix}
  \ \mathcal C & & S(\tau) \\%
   & \mathsf {Set}
%%%
 \ncline[nodesepB=1.5pt]{1,1}{1,3} \ncline{1,1}{2,2}
 \ncline[nodesepA=1pt]{1,3}{2,2}
\end{psmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]