# How do I ensure that edges of a TikZ cube are parallel?

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

I sometimes find myself typesetting commutative cubes using TikZ. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset
{
  over/.style={preaction={draw=white,-,line width=6pt}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep={2.5em},row sep={2.5em},
    text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]
  {
      |(e)|  X X X X & & |(0)|   X_0     \\
    & |(1)|  X_1     & & |(01)|  X_{01}  \\
      |(2)|  X_2     & & |(02)|  X_{02}  \\
    & |(12)| X_{12}  & & |(012)| X_{012} \\
  };

  \draw[->] (e)  to (2);
  \draw[->] (0)  to (02);
  \draw[->] (e)  to (0);
  \draw[->] (2)  to (02);

  \draw[->,over] (1)  to (12);
  \draw[->]      (01) to (012);
  \draw[->,over] (1)  to (01);
  \draw[->]      (12) to (012);

  \draw[->] (e)  to (1);
  \draw[->] (0)  to (01);
  \draw[->] (2)  to (12);
  \draw[->] (02) to (012);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem that I often encounter is that if one of the nodes is larger than the others, then my cube is a little distorted.

[image: cube0]

My ad hoc fix is to adjust the width of one of the colums, for example by changing the first line in the matrix to

```
|(e)|  X X X X & & |(0)|   X_0     &[1em] \\
```

Then the result is pretty good:

[image: cube1]

Another thing I tried is changing the `column sep` and `row sep` options to:

```
column sep={5em,between origins},row sep={5em,between origins}
```

but then the edges are still not quite parallel:

[image: cube2]

I'm quite satisfied with the look of the second picture, but this method has a disadvantage that I have to guess a good offset value which is usually cumbersome. Is there a way of making TikZ figure out this value on its own? Or maybe there is a better way of using `between origins` or something else entirely?

Comment: Imagine you would like to anchor the 120 degree angle of node `12` if you write 12.120 TikZ wil think that this is a number and you will spend lots of time thinking what might be the problem. Hence, don't do numbers in node names.

Comment: @percusse Your advice is appreciated but it doesn't apply here. It is customary to index vertices of an $(n+1)$-cube by subsets of the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$. I find it really helpful for the node names to follow this convention and if I am typesetting a cube it is very unlikely that I will have to modify any angles.

Comment: Please take a look on my cubes here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234151

Comment: Why do you think that the edges of the last solution are not parallel? In fact, they are.

Comment: Well you have been warned.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I have seen this post. The edges in the last picture are not parallel, I checked it with a ruler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `between origins` is the right one. The problem is that this option is taken into account only in the first row, and there you are specifying three columns, not four. The effect can be amplified:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset
{
  over/.style={preaction={draw=white,-,line width=6pt}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep={1.5em,between origins},row sep={1em,between origins},nodes={inner sep=0.2pt}]
  {
      |(e)|  X & & |(0)|   X  \\
    & |(1)|  X & & |(01)|  X  \\
      |(2)|  X & & |(02)|  X  \\
    & |(12)| X & & |(012)| X \\
  };

  \draw[->] (e)  to (2);
  \draw[->] (0)  to (02);
  \draw[->] (e)  to (0);
  \draw[->] (2)  to (02);

  \draw[->,over] (1)  to (12);
  \draw[->]      (01) to (012);
  \draw[->,over] (1)  to (01);
  \draw[->]      (12) to (012);

  \draw[->] (e)  to (1);
  \draw[->] (0)  to (01);
  \draw[->] (2)  to (12);
  \draw[->] (02) to (012);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: original]

If the four column is added to the first row:

```
  \matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep={1.5em,between origins},row sep={1em,between origins},nodes={inner sep=0.2pt}]
  {
      |(e)|  X & & |(0)|   X & \\
    & |(1)|  X & & |(01)|  X  \\
      |(2)|  X & & |(02)|  X  \\
    & |(12)| X & & |(012)| X \\
  };
```

Then the result is the expected one:

[image]

Comment: This appears to work and this is the solution that I like the most.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `tikz-cd` for such diagramms. You might find it visually more pleasing if you tweak around with the indices a bit. Have a look on the right side where I have smashed all the indices in order to get a more even look on the left side.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,column sep={5em,between origins}
    ,row sep={5em,between origins}
    ]
    XXXX \arrow{rr}\arrow{dd}\arrow{dr} & & X_{\mathrlap{0}} \arrow{dd}\arrow{dr} & \\
    & X_1 \arrow[crossing over]{rr} & & X_{\mathrlap{01}} \arrow{dd} \\
    X_2 \arrow{rr}\arrow{dr} & & X_{\mathrlap{02}} \arrow{dr} & \\
    & X_{12} \arrow{rr}\arrow[<-,crossing over]{uu} & & X_{\mathrlap{012}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to work, but I don't want to use `tikz-cd`. The main reason I like typesetting diagrams in TikZ is that I can specify objects and arrows separately. Doing it `tikz-cd` style defeats the purpose in my mind. However, explicitly specifying the last column with the ampersand in the last row fixes the problem.